# How to describe this trend in the figure?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction

[image]

I would like to emphasize the percentage change in the treatment cost by the percentage changes in the share of non-hazard waste.

Can I say "Every 10 percentile increment in the share of non-hazard waste in total waste leads to a 10-percentile decrement in the unit treatment cost"

If not accurate, how to describe the trend in the figure?

Comment: You mean "every 10 **percent**", not *percentile*.  A [percentile](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/percentiles.html) is a grouping into one of 100 groups.

Comment: Every 10% increment in the share of non-hazard waste in total waste leads to a 10% decrement in the unit treatment cost? I was afraid people might be confused by the base of each 10% increment because an increase from 10% by 10% is 11%, not 20%...

Comment: That's true, "a 10% increment" could be ambiguous.  But my point was that *percentile* is definitely wrong.

Comment: Ok, no percentile. Do you have any idea how to make the sentence more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many alternatives.  The key idea is that an increase by 10 percentage points results in a decrease of one dollar.

One possibility is to reverse this and say

> A decrease of ten percentage points in the share of non-hazard waste increases the unit treatment cost by one dollar.

The difference between a ten percent decrease, and a ten percentage point decrease is that the change from 30% to 15% is a 50% decrease (it is halving) but a 15 percentage point decrease.  See [a comical take on this](https://xkcd.com/985/).

Answer (score 0):

The suggested wording **will** emphasize the treatment cost benefit as a function of the percentage of non-hazard waste, which i think is the intention of the question.

Answer (score -1):

The math relationship you are describing is an 'inverse-ratio', which describes an output (waste) that gets smaller as the input (cost) gets larger. In your example, this is a 'proportional inverse-ratio', where every new unit of cost results in the same amount of new reduction in waste.